# Working with multiple partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Good day

I am working with 7 partial views on my index page.

**Index.cshtml** (code section that creates the partial views in their own tabs)

```
@model project1.Models.MasterModel
<div class="tab-content col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="margin-bottom:110px;">
<div id="partial1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    @Html.Partial("partial1", Model)
</div>
<div id="partial2" class="tab-pane fade in">
    @Html.Partial("partial2", Model)
</div>
<div id="partial3" class="tab-pane fade in">
    @Html.Partial("partial3", Model)
</div>
<div id="partial4" class="tab-pane fade in">
    @Html.Partial("partial4", Model.Owners)
</div>
<div id="partial5" class="tab-pane fade in">
    @Html.Partial("partial5", Model)
</div>
<div id="partial6" class="tab-pane fade in">
    @Html.Partial("partial6", Model)
</div>
<div id="partial7" class="tab-pane fade in">
    @Html.Partial("partial7", Model)
</div>
```

On `partial1` I have a submit button that should populate the other partial views with the information that is submitted on the first partial view.

My `Model` consist of 7 models (one for each partial view)

**MasterModel.cs**

```
public class MasterModel
{
    public DisplayPartial1 view1 {get;set;}

    public DisplayPartial2 view2 {get;set;}

    public DisplayPartial3 view3 {get;set;}

    public DisplayPartial4 view4 {get;set;}

    public DisplayPartial5 view5 {get;set;}

    public DisplayPartial6 view6 {get;set;}

    public DisplayPartial7 view7 {get;set;}
}
```

In my controller's Index Action result I create a new instance of the MasterModel and then I create new instances for all the sub models and return to the Index view.

**MainController.cs**

```
// Global variable used and returned by all partial views
MasterModel main = new MasterModel();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    MasterModel master = new MasterModel();
    master.view1 = new DisplayPartial1 ();
    master.view2 = new DisplayPartial2 ();
    master.view3 = new DisplayPartial3 ();
    master.view4 = new DisplayPartial4 ();
    master.view5 = new DisplayPartial5 ();
    master.view6 = new DisplayPartial6 ();
    master.view7 = new DisplayPartial7 ();
    return View(master);
}

public ActionResult MyPartial1()
{
    return PartialView("MyPartial1", master);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPartial1(MasterModel model, string submitButton)
{
    if(submitButton == "GetInfo")
    {
        /*Process input values*/
        //wcf service return data
        main.view1.id = serviceObject.Id;
        ...
        main.view4.name = serviceObject.Name;
        ...
    }
    return PartialView("MyPartial1", master);
}
```

When `MyPartial1` is returned then the other 6 partial view do not update with the assigned information until I do a submit call with a java script that looks like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#input1').change(function () {
            $('form').submit();
        });
        $('#input2').change(function () {
            $('form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**An Example Partial view**  (all the partial views work on the same principals)

```
@model OperatorLicense.Models.MasterModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyPartial1", "Operator", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "MyPartial1",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "Post"
}, new { id = "MyPartial1" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.view1.SerialNumber, new { id="SerialNumber", @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.view1.SerialNumber) })
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to refresh the other partial views when the `MyPartial1` partial view has returned so that the assaigned values can be displayed on the required partial view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OnSuccess` or `OnComplete` property of `AjaxOptions` class.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyPartial1", "Operator", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "MyPartial1",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    OnSuccess="partial1Success"
}, new { id = "MyPartial1" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.view1.SerialNumber, new { id="SerialNumber", @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.view1.SerialNumber) })
    ...
}
```

define `partial1Success` method in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function partial1Success(){
       // write your other partial view refresh logic here
    }
</script>
```

`partial1Success` method called after from submit successfully.

Comment: I tried it.  I can see that it is working, but it is causing an infinite loop of submit calls. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't know your whole logic. just try to find which part is causing infinite submit. and remove that part.